# JSON File has square brackets instead of curly brackets

Tags: python, ios, json, django, uitableview

I have the following Django code:

```
def jsonLiveLeaderboard(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        """
            select username as User, CAST(floor((count(Goals)/2)-(if(sum(Loss)>0,1,0))) as UNSIGNED) as Round, CAST(sum(Win) as UNSIGNED) as Wins, CAST(sum(Goals) as UNSIGNED) as Goals, CAST(sum(Loss) as UNSIGNED) as Losses from
            (select u.username as username, s.campaignno as campaign, if(f.hometeamscore>f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Win, if(f.hometeamscore<f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Loss, f.hometeamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.hometeamid and s.user_id = u.id union all
            select u.username as username, s.campaignno as campaign, if(f.awayteamscore>f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Win, if(f.awayteamscore<f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Loss, f.awayteamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.awayteamid and s.user_id = u.id) t
            group by username, campaign
            having Losses = 0
            order by Round DESC, Wins DESC, Goals DESC
        """)

    json_data = json.dumps(cursor.fetchmany(size=5))

    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

This code produces the following output:

```
[["tingeyal", 3, 5, 16, 0], ["shanu", 2, 4, 12, 0], ["kevry", 2, 4, 12, 0], ["d_whoppa", 2, 4, 9, 0], ["kriste8403", 2, 4, 8, 0]]
```

as can be seen at:

https://str8red.com/jsonLiveLeaderboard/

My results are typically returned in { brackets and not [ brackets.

My end game is to use the son output in an iOS UITableView.  Is my current format going to be an issue?

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: What language is that? It's not Swift or Objective-C. Is that Javascript? You should add that info to your question title and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: It is Django, I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets in JSON indicate an array. [example](https://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html)

Were you just concerned with getting square brackets back in your JSON result or were you unable to use the Json result?

*edited to fix link description

Comment: I have not tried to use the result yet as I thought I would check if I had already done something incorrectly,  I will read your link :)